# Is there a way to get just a specific string from another string?

Tags: python

Let say I have the next string:

`string = "<dialog id="105">\xa<state>confirmed</state>\xa</dialog>"`

The length of this string may vary. Is there a way that I can get just the `confirmed` string in python?

Comment: This looks like XML. You can look into XML parsing libraries. You can also look into regular expressions.

Comment: You mean you want to get the content of the `<state>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
string = '<dialog id="105">\\xa<state>confirmed</state>\\xa</dialog>'
print(re.findall(r'confirmed', string)[0])
```

You can use Python's `re` package and use `findall` function to get what you want.

Comment: using re is overkill and will also return any instance of "confirmed," which will matter if the length of the string may vary.

Comment: Agreed, but just another way to do it.

Comment: While it is the accepted answer, this only works on a specific case. The answer below is the much better and robust solution.

Answer (score 4):

I modified your xml string a bit and was able to get confirmed as output, Below is the code:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    string = '''<dialog id="105"><state>confirmed</state></dialog>'''
    root = ET.fromstring(string)
    print(root)
    for child in root:
        if child.tag == 'state':
            print(child.text)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Not quite because I'm getting that string from an UPD packet, so those **\xa** are included.

The string that I'm receiving is way longer. I just took a part of it to make the question more understandable.